# OAuthRequestFilter (or ContainerRequestFilter) not working inside AbstractFeature - "org.apache.cxf.resource.method" is null

Tags: filter, cxf, handler, requesthandler

We are using CXF 3.x, project has classes `MyFeature extends AbstractFeature` and `MyFilter extends OAuthRequestFilter.

Inside `MyFeature` class object of `MyFilter` created as `MyFilter myFilter = new MyFilter (classObj);` where `classObj` is object of class on which filter needs to be applied.

When I hit endpoint it throws error as 403.

**Further when I used debugger and LOG messages, I come to know that inside file `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.security.AbstractAuthorizingInInterceptor` (cxf-core version 3.0.4.redhat-621159) there is function `getTargetMethod` and inside that method evaluation of `BindingOperationInfo` and `m.get("org.apache.cxf.resource.method")` are coming `null`, due to which I am getting 403.**

Note: We are using osgi (jboss) bundle as deployment strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters executed by `JAXRSInInterceptor` are in `unmarshal` state. In this state `org.apache.cxf.resource.method` remains `null`.  I created interceptor in state `PRE_STREAM` and at that time `org.apache.cxf.resource.method` gives you correct name that should be executed.